# Where's Irune and the book of Plenix?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I need to get the Book of Plenix from Irune, but I'm not even sure if that's a person in the Citadel or a planet in the galaxy.

Where do I find Irune?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Irune** is a planet in the **Aethon Cluster.**

This system doesn't appear until you've advanced to a certain point in the main story (I believe after Tuchanka). Once you're able to travel there, you want to head to the **Aru** system (default from the relay). There you will be able to scan **Irune** to recover the book after pinging the planet.

Comment: It's either Tuchanka or the attack on the Citadel.  Those happened basically one after the other for me, so I can't remember what opened up in between.

Answer (score 0):

Aethon Cluster will not populate until Ashley Williams is on your team.

Comment: Ash is DEAD in mine :) It showed after Citadel

Comment: Anthony cluster will populate after Tuchanka. You don't have to have Ashley.